# Excel and Google Sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am in a bit of a pickle here. I have a certain formula that checks if a certain company is do not contact list. If so the formula notifies as Blocklist! The formula below

```
if(countif(Block!B:K,REGEXEXTRACT(N2, "\@([0-9A-Za-z-]+)\."))>0,"BLOCKLIST!","")
```

The do not contact list are on a sperate tab called Block.

The issue with this current formula is that it will only notify if its an exact match. Eg if the DNC has google.com and their domain is @google.com.

I'm trying to make this a contain formula. For instance, if google.com is in the DNC list and their domain is googlemail.com, the formula will pick this up as block, as it contains the word google on the DNC list.

Link to [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BLq7eM9nKwUJJyERpODm9RYdAO2q4E8xeNE2r5qVJWQ/edit#gid=0)

I have tested some formula on column P, but I failed to make it work.

Comment: please allow access to your spreadsheet, it's private

Comment: What about using wildcards `*`? In Excel, you could do `*Mycriteria*`. Can't you do it in Google Sheets?

Comment: Apologies for not giving access - its open now

Comment: Wildcards can be done, but i couldn't make it work mainly because its on another tab and there can we numerous one of them

Comment: I don't fully understand what do you want to do. Would you like to only get the exact domain *example.com*? Do you want to block all the domains derived from a company, like *example.com*, *example.es*, *example.net* ? All of that avoiding *examplesomething.com*? Please,  provide more examples.